# Injecting Outliers in the dataset in r

Tags: r, outliers

I am working on generating a dataset with n=20 in a linear regression y=b0+b1x+e* (i am not sure whether i should include the error term in my code).

- x and y are normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
- the error term e is also said to be normally distributed with mean 0 and sd 
  1, BUT with 10% identical outliers in the y direction

My code starts with this

```
n11 <- 20
m1 <- 0
sd1<- 1
b0 <- 0
b1 <- 1
x <- rnorm(n11,m1, sd1)

y <- b0 + b1*x + e11

e11 <- rnorm(n11,m1, sd1)

data11<-data.frame(y,x,e11,b0,b1)

model1<-lm(y~x, data=data11)
```

I don't know how and where I should put in code the said 10% identical outliers in the y direction I need help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Regards to `10% identical outliers in the y direction`: 1. `identical outliers` means the same value? 2. `y direction` means in `y` variable?

Comment: Is there something else given about the error? Do you know that b0=0 and b1=1? I'm asking because Y being N(0,1) isn't something trivial since we define Y in terms of other variables instead of simulating it independently.